# Difference between Binary encoded AVRO v/s JSON encoded AVRO

Tags: python, python-3.x, avro

Based on the AVRO documentation, for binary encoded AVRO, i understand that there are 2 important aspects. One is the AVRO schema i.e: .avsc (which is represented in JSON) that describes the fields of the data and then there is the actual data that is binary encoded.

There is very little documentation on JSON encoded AVRO and so i am trying to understand if it follows the same semantics where we will have AVRO schema file in JSON format (i.e: .avsc file) followed by the payload which would be data encoded in JSON ? Or whether its just the payload alone which is JSON encoded completely where the value against each key is binary encoded ?

Trying to experiment with Python so any leads/sample code would help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The binary and JSON encodings have to do only with the payload itself. For example, if you had a schema like this:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "test",
  "fields" : [
    {"name": "a", "type": "long"},
    {"name": "b", "type": "string"}
  ]
}
```

And you had a record whose `a` field has a value of `27` and whose `b` field has a value of `foo` then the binary encoding would be the following hex byte sequence:

```
36 06 66 6f 6f
```

Whereas the JSON encoding would simply be:

```
{"a": 27, "b": "foo"}
```

The binary format is much more compact, but of course the JSON format is much more readable.

When you talk about the semantics of having a schema and a payload encoded as one output, you are really talking about avro container files (https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Object+Container+Files) and those only use the binary encoding. There is no specification for a container file that uses the JSON encoding. An avro file can be parsed without any prior knowledge because the schema is baked into the file, but JSON encoded avro will always need the schema as an input since it is not baked into the result like an avro file is.

If you are using Python, the standard `avro` library doesn't support the JSON encoding as far as I know, but `fastavro` does. The docs for reading and writing are below:

https://fastavro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/json_reader.html
https://fastavro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/json_writer.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation @Scott. Couple of follow up questions:

1) You mentioned "An avro file can be parsed without any prior knowledge because the schema is baked into the file". Are you referring to a binary encoded AVRO payload without the schema file or are your referring to binary encoded Object Container files in AVRO ?

2) Given that one *MUST* have the AVRO schema file to read JSON encoded AVRO payload, can a generic JSON schema inference engine directly take the JSON encoded AVRO payload and make sense of it without the need to refer to the schema file ?

Comment: 1) I was referring to the object container files. If all you have is binary encoded avro like the `36 06 66 6f 6f` in my answer, you definitely will need to provide a schema to parse that.
2) You could try to do that (and there might be libraries that attempt that), but it would have many opportunities to fail. For example, in my answer where I have the JSON output and `"b": "foo"`, something trying to infer the schema wouldn't know if the `b` field is a string type or an enum type.